# how the data is destructured in this example?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, miragejs

im making a project diary App by follwing an article. it uses redux toolkit and miraj as a fake server.
it has a component named Editor

```
 const Editor: FC = () => {
  const { currentlyEditing: entry, canEdit, activeDiaryId } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.editor
  );
  const [editedEntry, updateEditedEntry] = useState(entry);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const saveEntry = async () => {
    if (activeDiaryId == null) {
      return showAlert('Please select a diary.', 'warning');
    }
    if (entry == null) {
      http
        .post<Entry, { diary: Diary; entry: Entry }>(
          `/diaries/entry/${activeDiaryId}`,
          editedEntry
        )
        .then((data) => {
          if (data != null) {
            const { diary, entry: _entry } = data;
            dispatch(setCurrentlyEditing(_entry));
            dispatch(updateDiary(diary));
          }
        });
```

as a newbie im unable to understand following:

```
enter code here const { currentlyEditing: entry, canEdit, activeDiaryId } = useSelector(
```

in this line to my understanding entry is a type. but there is no type or interface of entry in article.
2ndly

```
 .post<Entry, { diary: Diary; entry: Entry }>(
          `/diaries/entry/${activeDiaryId}`,
```

we are making a post request and in miraj server we have defined routes as:

```
this.post('/diaries/entry/:id', diary.addEntry);
```

i dont understand this :id part. how we would get the id over here?

and last thing :) in this line:
const { diary, entry: _entry } = data;
dispatch(setCurrentlyEditing(_entry));
why there is underscore before entry? and same question like above that is it a type for typescript or some destructuring method that i dont know.

Comment: this is the article im following
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/redux-real-world-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> code here const { currentlyEditing: entry, canEdit, activeDiaryId } = useSelector(
> ```
>
> in this line to my understanding entry is a type. but there is no type
> or interface of entry in article. 2ndly

No, this is not a type. This is JS lingo for renaming destructured properties. The code is simply taking `currentlyEditing` and renaming it to `entry`. This is also the case for `const { diary, entry: _entry } = data`, hence `dispatch(setCurrentlyEditing(_entry))`.

> ```
> this.post('/diaries/entry/:id', diary.addEntry);
> ```
>
> i dont understand this :id part. how we would get the id over here?

This is basically a placeholder for retrieving dynamic parameters that you collect from your URL, for example if the URL is `http://www.website.org/diaries/entry/123`, then `id=123`, which mirage will automatically parse out from the route. Please refer to the doc section [here](https://miragejs.com/docs/main-concepts/route-handlers/#dynamic-paths-and-query-params)